# Strange visual bug in youtube player

Tags: video, youtube

For some reason I don't understand, I've been having this problem for a long time only for youtube player.
this problem only occurs on youtube player and only occurs on debian based operating systems (I didn't have the same problem when using windows 10,I had the same problem when using kali linux I'm using ubuntu now and the same problem continues.)

When the visual interface is active in the youtube player (what comes out when you move the mouse), colorful lines appear on the screen, usually at the bottom of the screen.

these lines are different every time the visual interface is active and completely random.

and strangely these lines disappear with the interface after a few seconds

I leave screenshots for you to understand the problem more easily
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CC9B.png)
note: this problem happens regardless of browser

[hardware info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaD5D.png)

Comment: maybe you GPU isn't compatible to the driver you are using. You could trying switch different drivers.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post your hardware specifications, particularly the graphics, along with the Ubuntu release/version.

Answer (score 0):

Disable in settings of yours browsers the "Use hardware acceleration when available". For some reason is on by default.